# How to find out the drag source component in the drop target TransferHandler?

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, java-5

Question is regarding **Java 5** and Drag n Drop.

Is there a way to determine the drag source **component** in the drop target `TransferHandler`?

I need to know this in my `canImport(..)` or `importData(..)` method in order to take different actions for transfer data of the same type or `DataFlavor`.

The way I have achieved this currently is to hijack the DataFlavor 'Human Readable Field' and set a string action, resulting something like this:

```
DataFlavor localCopyFooFlavor = new DataFlavor(Foo.class, "COPY");
DataFlavor localEditFooFlavor = new DataFlavor(Foo.class, "EDIT");
```

Then use this field to decide what action to take.
I pretty sure this is wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out.

The key is to create a DataFlavor per drop target component. So here I have 4 targets which accept drops of type foo, 3 buttons and 1 panel.

```
fooCopyButtonFlavor   = new DataFlavor(FooCopyButtonTransferData.class,   "Foo 'Copy Button' Transfer Data");
fooEditButtonFlavor   = new DataFlavor(FooEditButtonTransferData.class,   "Foo Entry 'Edit Button' Transfer Data");
fooDeleteButtonFlavor = new DataFlavor(FooDeleteButtonTransferData.class, "Foo Entry 'Delete Button' Transfer Data");
fooDialogPanelFlavor  = new DataFlavor(FooDialogPanelTransferData.class, "Foo Entry 'Dialog Panel' Transfer Data")
```

I decided to wrap up my Foo state class.

And make this wrapper implements a custom interface I named TransferDataStrategy.  Doing this now allows me to perform different actions in the importData(...) function for the same flavors.

```
public interface TransferDataStrategy<MODEL>
{
    MODEL getModel();

    OptionStrategy getOptionStrategy();
}
```

My `Transferable` implementations (which can be thought of as the SOURCE of the drag) can now drive what happens on drop for the same `DataFlavor` (or Drop Target Component) by returning different strategies.

```
public class SourceOneTransferOperation implements Transferable
{
    public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor) throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException
    {
        if (flavor.equals(FooDataFlavor.fooCopyButtonFlavor)) {
            TransferDataStrategy<Foo> tds = new FooCopyAAA(model);
            return tds;
        }
     ...
    }
}
```

Notice Source Two Below is also supports FooCopyButtonFlavor, but returns a different strategy.

```
public class SourceTwoTransferOperation implements Transferable
{
    public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor) throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException
    {
        if (flavor.equals(FooDataFlavor.fooCopyButtonFlavor)) {
            TransferDataStrategy<Foo> tds = new FooCopyBBB(model);
            return tds;
        }
     ...
    }
}
```

This is quite hard to explain but hopefully it might help.